# Chart.js how to expand fidelity of only a portion of Y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

See the chart picture below. We need to expand the Y axis from 0-10 so it increases to about 2x the size and shows each number. How do we do that? :D

[image]

**code**

```
 const data = {
  labels: dates,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'SIS',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: sis_data,
  },
  {
    label: 'Mood',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(99, 255, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(99, 255, 132)',
    data: mood_data,
  },
  {
    label: 'Sleep',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(99, 132, 255)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(99, 132, 255)',
    data: sleep_data,
  }]
};

  const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {}
  };

var myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
```